# Map N,S,E,W Angle system System to 360° Angle System

Tags: python, coordinates, angle

I have a coordinate system where North has the angle value 1. East +0.707 and West -0.707. South has the angle 0.
It's very annoying to calculate angle deltas in this angle system. Is there a nice way to convert it to a standard 0 to 360 degree coordinate system?
Python solution preferred but I'm more interested in the operations instead of ready to use implementation.

Comment: Do you just want to remap NSEW, or do you need to map arbitrary orientations? It seems as if the coordinate system is not linear (E/W is not in the middle of N/S) – what is the formula to translate intermediate values?

Comment: You're describing a nonlinear angle measurement.  It doesn't really make sense.  If south is 0 and east is 0.707, then north should be 1.414.  You need to be much more specific about your definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That angle system is very weird. It seems like your "angle" is calculated as `sin(radians(d/2))` where `d` is actual angle in degrees (with south being 0° and east 90°). You can invert this:

```
>>> from math import *
>>> ewns = [0.707, -0.707, 1.0, 0.0]
>>> [degrees(asin(x) * 2) for x in ewns]
[89.98269667432403, -89.98269667432403, 180.0, 0.0]
```

Optionally `round` and add `% 360` to get 0..360 instead of -180..180:

```
>>> [round(degrees(asin(x) * 2)) % 360 for x in ewns]
[90, 270, 180, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

0.707 is the cosine of 45°. So your current system shows you the cosine of your angle divided by 2, as I would expect a 90° value for West. If you apply the transformation 180/pi * arccos(x) * 2, where x is your current value, you will get a 0° to 360° value, where 0° or 360° will be North, and 180° will be South.

The 180/pi factor is there to convert from the radians output of the arccos function.

Comment: Use factor 57.297, pi is not a name in python. But for python I would suggest make a simple class Degrees360() with member cosine(self, x): return cos(x/57.297)  and another member  def sinus(self, x): return sin(x/57.297).

Comment: pi is not a name but is defined in the math library, which I could have clarified. However I do not think using 57.297 does any good as it is really a magic number. And I would not create a class for such a simple task. All in all, tobias_k has already given a clear and good answer.